# Everytime I restart, I lose changes to list of Favorite launchers in Xubuntu whisker's menu?

Tags: xubuntu, launcher

This started to happen a few weeks ago. I had already added some favorites, which I don't lose. But new favorites that I've added since a couple of weeks, are lost everytime I restart the computer.

Where is the text file storing the list of Favorites in Xubuntu's whisker menu? I think this may have something to do with permissions on this file, which means that changes are not being saved. But that is just a suspicion, so if anyone has an alternative explanation, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my system (Xubuntu 15.10) it is

```
~/.config/xfce4/panel/whiskermenu-1.rc
```

and permissions are 664 (-rw-rw-r--)

Comment: Actually, this is very weird. The file `whiskermenu-1.rc` keeps changing, and I keep losing changes to the Favorites list after a restart. It doesn't happen everytime. Damn, I have no idea how to diagnose what is going on ...